# How to open .doc files containing XML code in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, xml, microsoft-word, doc

I have a .doc file that contains XML formatting code. If I open it on Windows with MS Word it perfectly works showing tables, texts and so on.

This is how it looks on MS Word:
[image: MS word opening the file]

If I open it in LibreOffice it only shows XML lines like this (this is the header only):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve">
```

There exists some way of opening it into ubuntu?

---

### **Update**

I already tried LibreOffice Calc loading the XML source but it doesn't work. 
More precisely, when I select the file, there is nothing to map in the box *Map to document* and I can't press the *Import* button. I also tried changing the extension into .xml, still nothing.

Answer (score 3):

LibraOffice Calc allows you to open XML files by loading it using:

-> `Data` -> `XML Source`

[image]

[image: XML Source Dialog]

More info can be found [here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Calc/XMLSource)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work..

Comment: @granmirupa What exactly do you mean when you say it "doesn't work?" Are you unable to open the dialog box? Does it populate the spreadsheet cells from the XML data, but with incorrect formatting? Does it throw an error message? Are you still seeing just raw XML? We need to know what  steps you've tried and what exactly you're seeing if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: @NickWeinberg When I select the file, there is nothing to map in the box 'Map to document' and I can't press import. I also tried changing the extension into .xml